# Client want to see report before review from manager

Tags: professionalism, clients

I have this client who is insisting to see the report early. Our company have a policy to have a 'high check' before client views it. High check is where other colleague, probably senior OR manager level, reviews the report.

How should I handle this client?

Comment: Who is paying your paychecks? Follow your company procedure. At most, comment the client request to your boss so he can decide if the company (not you) will make an exception for that customer.

Comment: I think you're phrasing this question wrong. You should be asking `I have this client who is insisting to see the report today, even though I will need until tomorrow to finish our required quality control checks on that report. How should I handle this client?` So the choice is clear what you should do. Just say it's not possible to finish it earlier than the agreed deadline. If they are pushy then you have to push back nicely and explain how it's in their interests that you complete the normal quality checks. They want the report correct don't they??

Answer (score 11):

Your company no doubt has a **very good reason** for internally reviewing these reports before releasing them to clients. It's likely that sometime in the past, a report with errors made it into a client's hands.

It's very likely that the person in your position who released that report lost her job over it, and your company lost that client.

You might ask people in your company why they have this policy. In the meantime, do not break it: do not give this unreviewed report to your client.  If they insist, ask for the help of your manager or the sales person handling this account. But do not break the rule. Seriously. The rule is for **your** protection.

Comment: I would add that you could see if your reviewing manager would be willing to look it over early so you can still get it to the customer, but only if your customer isn't making this sort of request a regular habit.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you do is inform your boss of the issue. Then you and he get together and determine what the response to the client should be and if it is possible to get the report early with a review.  These reviewes are institituted usually for a very good reason. However, you might ask the client why they need it earlier than usual so that you can give your boss that information. If it is a good enough reason, your company might bypass the review int his one instance *(or ask the reviewer to stay late to do the review) but it is not your call at any rate. This is a senior mamangement call and the best you can do is pass it up to them after collecting the information they need to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 1):

You tell the client that you will see to it that the report will be in their hands as soon as your senior management signs off on it. Then you tell your management that the client wants to see the report early.

For obvious reasons, you simply cannot afford to send anything important to any client without sign-off from senior management. You don't want to take a chance on sending materials that haven't been reviewed and if you do, you should be fired for it.

I trust that you fully understand why I am taking such a hard line on sending unreviewed materials to clients no matter how much they want a bum's rush. Some things are just non-negotiable.

Wishing you well.

Note:

1. if the client explicitly says they want to take a chance, your management could have you send an unreviewed or a superficially reviewed report, but such a report would have to carry a "Draft" watermark.
2. Sending a "Draft" report would make sense only if nobody on your side of the fence expects anything more than minor alterations between the "Draft" and "Final" versions of the report, the client states in writing that the customary lead time between "Draft" and "Final" is substantial for them AND the client is assuming all risks that are inherent in reading a report in "Draft" form.
3. Caveat: clients have been known to expeditiously say that they will take all the risks and say something else afterwards, when something goes sufficiently wrong. At which point, the word "litigation"  comes up. If you are thinking that I am not trusting the client one bit, you're right about me. I don't trust this client one bit for the same reason I don't trust anyone who makes slick demands and offer guarantees that are on the slick side of things. It takes only one bad, litigious client to make everybody's life miserable.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be for your boss to approve a draft delivery early and a final delivery at the originally agreed upon time.  Since it's not a final product and would be delivered with the explicit knowledge that it's a work in progress, he may be willing to relax the level of review required prior to release.  Draft status would typically be marked on every page; preferably with a [watermark](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-a-draft-watermark-to-your-document-HA102809785.aspx) for maximum visibility to make sure that the customer can't reasonably claim to have "forgotten" that what they have isn't final.

A final point is that if your boss refuses to authorize an early delivery, and the customer doesn't accept the fact; you will probably need to bring your client into direct communication with either your boss, someone from your companies contracting office, or someone farther up the management chain who does have the authority to create and enforce company policy.

Bending the rules to make difficult customers happy or choosing to stand on the letter of the contract/company policy at the risk of ending the business relationship are responsibilities of relatively senior leadership; and not something that ordinary workers should be making decisions about.

Answer (score 0):

Until the review has been done, you can honestly tell the client that you're still working on the document and you'll get it to them as soon as it's ready. If they object, offer to refer them to your boss (and tell him you're doing so) so he can give them the same answer and/or help the reviews happen faster.

Not every customer request is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I handle this client?

You tell the client about the company policy, and explain that it means they cannot see the report before your manager checks it.

If the client insists, you bring the request to management. It's likely that only management can change or circumvent your company policies.